# Can I Create a Functor Data Type That 'Looks' Like an Int?

Tags: haskell, types

I'm not sure if I'm being too ambitious here, but I'm attempting to construct an integer mod 12 data type for use in a music notation system. If possible I'd love to have values of this type be specifiable in practice simply using the numbers 0-11 (as opposed to writing "Note 11", for instance), and have the Note type be inferred by the type signatures of the functions that use it. I've created a clunky makeshift version of this using

```
type Note = Int
```

then simply composing any functions that act on Notes with a mod 12 function. This works perfectly well, but it's repetitive. It looks like the perfect spot for a functor, using something roughly along the lines of

```
instance Functor Note where
    fmap f = (`mod` 12).f
```

I think I could easily make that work if I wrote "Note 0" or something along those lines anytime I use the data type, but that's an exactly equivalent amount of typing to what I'm currently doing (though admittedly it's probably slightly less error prone). Lastly I'm aware that smart constructors are a closely related topic to what I'm working on, but as of yet I couldn't manage to make that work for my pipe dream setup. Is there any way I can have my cake (represent Notes with plain integers 0-11) and eat it too (define fmap for Notes) here, or am I being optimistic?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First, only types of kind `* -> *` can be made instances of the `Functor` class. `Note` has kind `*`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't get a functor instance here, because your type is too specific.  But don't despair – you can still pretty much get what you want!  We'll just use a *free-standing ordinary function* that does the same thing, instead of using a type class.  Here's the road map:

1. First, we'll define our `Note` type and make it safe: we'll use a smart constructor to ensure that all `Note`s hold an `Int` between `0` and `11`.
2. Next, we'll talk about `Functor` and why `Note` isn't one, as well as how to replace the functionality you want with an ordinary function.
3. Finally, we'll make `Note` support number-literal syntax.
4. We'll then show some examples of usage.
5. And we'll close out with the complete code.

---

So let's define our `Note` type.  We want it to be a thin wrapper around an integer, so we'll use a `newtype`:

```
newtype Note = MkNote Int deriving Eq
instance Show Note where
  show (MkNote 0)  = "A"
  show (MkNote 1)  = "A♯/B♭"
  show (MkNote 2)  = "B"
  show (MkNote 3)  = "C"
  show (MkNote 4)  = "C♯/D♭"
  show (MkNote 5)  = "D"
  show (MkNote 6)  = "D♯/E♭"
  show (MkNote 7)  = "E"
  show (MkNote 8)  = "F"
  show (MkNote 9)  = "F♯/G♭"
  show (MkNote 10) = "G"
  show (MkNote 11) = "G♯/A♭"
  show (MkNote _)  = error "internal error: invalid `Note'"
```

Now, to ensure that `Note`s are always 0–11, we use a smart constructor:

```
note :: Int -> Note
note = MkNote . (`mod` 12)
```

And we also provide a destructor:

```
getNote :: Note -> Int
getNote (MkNote i) = i
```

These functions will allow us to convert between `Note`s and `Int`s safely, so we can export the `Note` type but *not* the `MkNote` constructor to ensure that all `Note`s are between 0 and 11.

If we turn on the GHC extension [`PatternSynonyms`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.10.2/docs/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#pattern-synonyms), we can fake having an ordinary data type:

```
pattern Note :: Int -> Note
pattern Note i <- MkNote i where
  Note i = note i
```

This defines a new pattern `Note i` that, when pattern matching, corresponds to the `MkNote` constructor (the `<-` part), and when used in an expression corresponds to the `note` smart constructor (the `where …` part).

---

Now, you want to move between `Int` functions and `Note` functions, and you ask about creating a `Functor` instance.  Well, `Functor` isn't really what you're looking for here.  Let's look at the type class:

```
class Functor f where
  fmap :: (a -> b) -> (f a -> f b)
```

Hmm… we see that `f` is being *applied* to another type there.  But we can't do that with `Note`!  We say that `Note` has *kind* (the type of a type) `*`, which is the kind of all types; but `f` has kind `* -> *`, which is to say it's a type-level function that takes types to types.  This is why we can say

```
instance Functor Maybe where …
-- fmap :: (a -> b) -> (Maybe a -> Maybe b)
```

but not

```
-- instance Functor Note where …
-- fmap :: (a -> b) -> (Note a -> Note b)
```

So what can we do instead?  Well, just because the type class doesn't work doesn't mean we can't define our *own* mapping function:

```
nmap :: (Int -> Int) -> Note -> Note
nmap f = note . f . getNote
```

Since `note` does the `` (`mod` 12) `` thing you wanted, this is essentially the same as your definition, and this is the type that it must have: we can *only* `nmap` functions of type `Int -> Int`.  This is another reason `fmap` doesn't work – it must support *all* functions.

We can use this technique to define functions for working with multi-argument functions as well:

```
nmap2 :: (Int -> Int -> Int) -> Note -> Note -> Note
nmap2 f n1 n2 = note $ f (getNote n1) (getNote n2)
```

And if we want to work with functions that don't *return* `Note`s, we can do that:

```
nuse :: (Int -> a) -> Note -> a
nuse f = f . getNote

nuse2 :: (Int -> Int -> a) -> Note -> Note -> a
nuse2 f = f `on` getNote
-- `on` is from "Data.Function"
```

(Note that `nmap = note . nuse`, and similarly for `nmap2`.)

---

Finally, we can use this to support number literals.  In Haskell, numeric literals like `42` are equivalent to the expression `fromInteger (42 :: Integer)`, where [`fromInteger`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromInteger) is from the [`Num`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Num) type class.  So you can make `Note`s an instance of `Num`:

```
instance Num Note where
  (+) = nmap2 (+)
  (-) = nmap2 (-)
  (*) = error "Can't multiply `Note`s" -- Or @nmap2 (*)@

  negate = nmap negate
  abs    = id -- No-op; equivalent to @nmap abs@
  signum = nmap signum

  fromInteger = note . fromInteger -- 'Integer' → 'Int' → 'Note'
```

---

Putting all that together, here are some examples of what we can write.

A list of A♯s:

```
aSharps :: [Note]
aSharps = [ note 1, note (-11), note 13
          , 1,      -11,        13
          , Note 1, Note (-11), Note 13 ]
  -- All elements are equal
```

A function that turns Cs into As but leave other notes unchanged:

```
noCs :: Note -> Note
noCs 3 = 0
noCs n = n
```

and a different way of writing that function:

```
noCs' :: Note -> Note
noCs' 15 = 0
noCs' n = n
```

And so on and so forth

---

Finally, here's what all that code looks like put together; note that the module header doesn't export `MkNote` for safety.

```
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms #-}

module Note (
  Note(), pattern Note, note, getNote,
  nmap, nmap2, nuse, nuse2
  ) where

import Data.Function

newtype Note = MkNote Int deriving Eq
instance Show Note where
  show (MkNote 0)  = "A"
  show (MkNote 1)  = "A♯/B♭"
  show (MkNote 2)  = "B"
  show (MkNote 3)  = "C"
  show (MkNote 4)  = "C♯/D♭"
  show (MkNote 5)  = "D"
  show (MkNote 6)  = "D♯/E♭"
  show (MkNote 7)  = "E"
  show (MkNote 8)  = "F"
  show (MkNote 9)  = "F♯/G♭"
  show (MkNote 10) = "G"
  show (MkNote 11) = "G♯/A♭"
  show (MkNote _)  = error "internal error: invalid `Note'"

note :: Int -> Note
note = MkNote . (`mod` 12)

getNote :: Note -> Int
getNote (MkNote i) = i

pattern Note :: Int -> Note
pattern Note i <- MkNote i where
  Note i = note i

nmap :: (Int -> Int) -> Note -> Note
nmap f = note . f . getNote

nmap2 :: (Int -> Int -> Int) -> Note -> Note -> Note
nmap2 f n1 n2 = note $ f (getNote n1) (getNote n2)

nuse :: (Int -> a) -> Note -> a
nuse f = f . getNote

nuse2 :: (Int -> Int -> a) -> Note -> Note -> a
nuse2 f = f `on` getNote

instance Num Note where
  (+) = nmap2 (+)
  (-) = nmap2 (-)
  (*) = error "Can't multiply `Note`s" -- Or @nmap2 (*)@

  negate = nmap negate
  abs    = id -- No-op; equivalent to @nmap abs@
  signum = nmap signum

  fromInteger = note . fromInteger -- 'Integer' → 'Int' → 'Note'
```

Comment: Pattern synonyms are overkill, I think. You can just pattern match with numeric literals as long as you have `Num` and `Eq` instances.

Comment: @dfeuer: Good point!  I even did that later, but didn't put two and two together :-)

Answer (score 7):

The class you're looking for is `Num`: the literal syntax `0` in Haskell implicitly calls `fromInteger`. So you might write something like

```
newtype Note = Note Int
instance Num Note where
    fromInteger n = Note (fromInteger (n `mod` 12))
    Note a + Note b = Note ((a + b) `mod` 12)
```

and so on for the other `Num` operations. You might also like to use the Hackage package [modular-arithmetic](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/modular-arithmetic-1.2.1.1/docs/Data-Modular.html), which provides the `Mod Int 12` type and already has these operations available.